# Autoincrement amount of columns?

Tags: sql, sqlite, flutter, database-design

I have a simple question about SQL and specifically sqlite flutter plugin (sqflite).

Is it possible to create a database with 100 columns? If so, I mean, HoW should I create that?

Should I create 100 names for each column and then run `CREATE TABLE x1 TEXT, x2 TEXT, x3 TEXT, x4 TEXT, x5 TEXT.... x100 TEXT)` etc?

Or is there any way of accomplish what I describe? As I understand it might cause problem if there's only 15 elements saved into a database with 100 columns since the rest will be null right?

---

Here is a more specific description: A quiz, where the user also can create their customized quiz. So the variables will probably be question1, question2, etc up to 100, the maximum amount of questions for a quiz. The variables is not named for standard columns like "name", "surname", "age", etc.  I guess creating 100 variables for each column is the best approach, at least the best I know so far?

Comment: You can't create a database with 100 columns, but you can create a table with 100 columns, similar to as you describe.  There is no 'issue' with having NULL values..

Comment: So it's a good practice according to what I wanna accomplish?

Comment: Of course.  If you want to create a table you should use the ```CREATE TABLE..``` statement.

Comment: Nothing wrong about doing that if it fits your business requirements. Also, column values are nullable by default; this way you can have full rows of null values... if that makes sense to your business.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for the help. I create this database as described. :)

Comment: Its a table Rusben.  A database is comprised of many types of different objects, one of which is a table.

Comment: You have not shared enough information.  Other users have commented "of course" and "nothing wrong...", but that is simply because there is nothing keeping you from doing that.  But as a contrary example, you could also create hundreds of individual variables while programming even though an array might be more appropriate and manageable.  I perceive that your design is likely **not *normalized*** and that you may be going about it the wrong way.  But column names such as "x5" and "x100" are not descriptive and you really did not explain the relationship between the columns, etc.

Comment: @CPerkins Ok here is the plan: A quiz, where the user also can create their customized quiz. So the variables will probably be question1, question2, etc up to 100, the maximum amount of questions for a quiz. The variables is not named for standard columns like "name", "surname", "age", etc. I understand that my question might've been kind of confusing and not completely clear, but I guess creating 100 variables for each column is the best approach, at least the best I know so far? What do you think?

Comment: The questions should be stored as rows not columns.  You should review your data model.

Comment: Actually, creating one column for each possible question is not the best approach.  As I guessed before, this design is not normalized.  A better (standard, more efficient, scalable, etc.) approach is to store 1 question per row, perhaps like [QuizID], [QuestionNumber], [QuestionText], etc. which is related to another table with quiz details: [QuizID], [Topic], [QuizDate], etc.  BTW, this type of question is better for [Stack Exchange Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: @CPerkins Ok thanks. Actually, I didn't even think about keeping track of each question with a QuizID, that was a great idea. I think I'm going to use that approach rather than 100 variables. I was worrying about keeping track of the questions if the user stored multiple quizes, but storing a QuizID for the rows is of course a solution for that. Thank you very much.